# Why can't I use a decimal after e (exponent of 10) in Python?

Tags: python

So, why is `2e2` possible, but not `2e0.5` which should result in the same as `2*sqrt(10)`?

Comment: try `2*(10**0.5)`

Comment: Because that's [how the language is designed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals)...

Comment: that's a convention, also aplicable for many other programming language. For floating point "litteral" values, you can use an integer exponent only. This is linked with how floaintg  points are represetned internally (with an actual integer exponent). See first comment from Jean-François Fabre on a way to compute the result

Comment: that would complexify float parsing even more, too :)